# Dynamic toolbar items in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

How can we dynamically change the items of `.toolbar` modifier in SwiftUI?

I want to achieve something like the below, but it doesn't compile.

```swift
@State private var flag = false

var body: some View {
  //
  // some view code here
  //
  .toolbar {
    if flag {
      ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .principal) {
        Text("Something full width")
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
      }
    } else {
      ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
        Button("Something else") { ... }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could achieve it by combining `.principal` placement and `HStack` within it. In case you have any better ideas, that's really welcome and appreciated.

```swift
.toolbar {
  ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
    HStack {
      if flag {
        SearchBar(searchText: $searchText)
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)

        Button("Cancel") { flag = false }
      } else {
        Spacer()

        Button {
          flag = true
        } label: {
          Image(systemName: "text.magnifyingglass")
        }

        Button {
        } label: {
          Image(systemName: "phone.connection")
        }

        Button {
        } label: {
          Image(systemName: "line.3.horizontal")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When the `flag` is false
[image]

and then `true`
[image]

Comment: this is yet a different question than your first and your second questions. The idea in SO is to ask one question at a time.

Comment: principal puts it in the middle of the navigation bar on iPad.

Answer (score 2):

Put condition inside group, like

```
  .toolbar {
      ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .principal) {
        if flag {
          Button("Something") { ... }
        }
      }
      ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
       if !flag {
         Button("Something else") { ... }
       }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the same but in this way, there seems to be an unexpected space even when the item is not shown due to the flag. For example, when the flag is true, there's an unexpected space on tailing side even if I try to set infinity width frame to the principal item.